# StackOverflow Errors caused by flood fill: How to stop the error?

Tags: actionscript-3, stack-overflow

For my level editor in my game, I have a floodfill function. The map has a size of 3600 tiles (60 by 60), and I get a stack overflow error from my floodfill function (as it calls itself).

If I only floodfill a smaller radius, it works fine. How do I stop the error from occuring?

Alternatively, is there a way to tell the flash runtime to clear the stack as there is no need to return back to the function?

Comment: You just need to not use recursion. Can you post the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a flood fill function that doesn't rely on recursion because Flash's stack is quite limited. You can find some non-recursive ways on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Alternative_implementations

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you might be using a simple recursive implementation of flood-fill; that algorithm can create *deep* stacks. It's possible you could implement one of the more efficient queue based algorithms and save the stack, however I would suggest using the already built-in flood-fill capabilities of the `BitmapData` object.

`BitmapData` is provided by the Flash Player and has a pretty fast and stack friendly flood-fill implementation.

I was playing with flood-fill algorithms a while back and ended up using the built-in APIs mainly because of the speed advantage -- as well it's compiled C code vs ActionScript.

Here are the docs:

[flash.display.BitmapData floodFill()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#floodFill%28%29)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's a level editor, that means I need to store the data, and each tile is actually a movieclip.